# Google Sheets - Using MAXIFS within ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas, maxifs

I'm reaching out because I'm facing an issue in Google Sheets for which I can't find a solution and I'm certain someone here might have an answer to save me.

The situation is actually quite simple :

- In the D column of my sheet, I have a list of email addresses ;
- In the H column, for each of these addresses, I have a number of orders ;
- In the I column, I am trying to get, for the email address indicated in the D column, the maximum number of orders such as indicated in the H column.

[See a screenshot of the file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkSik.png)

Of course, this can really simply be done with the MAXIFS() formula such as follows :

`=maxifs(H:H;D:D;DX)`
where X is the n° of the lign.

Now, the issue appears when I try to transform this formula to an "ArrayFormula".

When trying to transform it, I tried typing :

`=arrayformula(maxifs(H:H;D:D;D:D))`

But it doesn't "expand" to the following lines.
The formula works for the line in which it is typed, but I can't get it to "replicate".

Does anyone here have an idea of how to solve this issue?

I wish you all a very pleasant week!

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=map(D3:D,lambda(z,if(z="",,vlookup(z,sort({D3:D,H3:H},2,0),2,))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAXIFS()` with `BYROW()` to make it dynamic. Try-

```
=BYROW(A3:A9,LAMBDA(x,MAXIFS(B3:B,A3:A,x)))
```

To refer full column as input parameter, use-

```
=BYROW(A3:INDEX(A3:A,COUNTA(A3:A)),LAMBDA(x,MAXIFS(B3:B,A3:A,x)))
```

[image]