# Google Sheets Formula combining ARRAYFORMULA, VLOOKUP, and MAX functions

Tags: google-sheets-formula, max, vlookup, array-formulas

I have a table (eg.- "TableA") with categories and values, like so:

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 9 |
| C | 6 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 5 |

I have another table with a list of unique categories, like so:

| Category | Max Value |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B |  |
| C |  |

The number of categories will change periodically, so I would like an ARRAYFORMULA to find the max value for each category.  There are thousands of categories, in fact, so I would like to avoid using a QUERY inside of an ARRAYFORMULA for performance's sake.  Any takers?

Comment: Note: a QUERY solution would be acceptable.

Comment: [this should be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75662751/5479575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the header cell with Max Value:

```
={"Max Value"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A = "",, VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY({'Data Sheet'!A:B}, "SELECT Col1, MAX(Col2) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1", 1), 2,)))}
```

Assumptions (fix the formula accordingly to your actual sheets):

- categories are statically set and are in column `A:A`
- data from the first table is on sheet `Data Sheet` in columns `A:B`.